# Python - Selenium xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I'm wondering why the code works sometimes and sometimes not. My IDE gives me this debugging error:

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:
> {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[2]"}
> (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)

```
    def find_followers(self):

    self.driver.get(URL+ACCOUNT)

    follow = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/header/section/ul/li[3]/a')
    follow.click()
    time.sleep(10)

    modal = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div/div/div[2]')
    
    for i in range(10):
        self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', modal)
        time.sleep(13)
```

I'm trying to make a script which goes to Instagram and opening up a Instagram accounts followers. The script goes well till this error. I've checked the XPath and it is surely right. I tried the script for a few days and it was working, but now when I tried again it dosen't. I'm new with Python and want to learn why this happen and how to solve it.

Comment: This is because you are using time.sleep(). Add link you test to your code

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the cookie popup and login to instagram in order to see the followers list. I'd recommend creating a second function called "initiate_instagram" that does that.

You could also login manually, because of 2 factor authentication.

Comment: Well, the script is already signing me in and goes to a accounts followers so I can see them. The issue is that this function is going to scroll down to see more followers in the list and be able to save the data.